# How to create a types only package on NPM

Tags: typescript, npm, monorepo

I would like to create a package (monorepo or NPM) that export only types so that in my project I can import them as such

```
import type { MyType } from '@acme/types'
```

I have tried the following solution but it doesn't work

**Project structure**

```
package.json
index.d.ts
```

**index.d.ts**

```
export type MyType = {
  name: string
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/types",
  "main": "./index.d.ts",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "default": "./index.d.ts",
      "import": "./index.d.ts",
      "types": "./index.d.ts"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```

When I want to import my type, I get this error

`File '/Users/acme/packages/types/index.d.ts' is not a module. ts(2306)`

I have also tried to rename `index.d.ts` to `index.ts`. Doesn't work either

Comment: Change main to index.js, moves types in exports to top (order matters), change default and import to index.js and index.mjs too. Create two files (index.js and index.mjs) that just export `{}`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850348/how-to-create-a-types-only-package-on-npm#comment133792643_75850348) You don't need a JavaScript module. You don't even need the `main`, `types`, or `exports` fields if you are using a top-level declaration file named `index.d.ts`. See [Declaration files > Publishing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) in the TS handbook.

Comment: I have removed `"type": "module"` `main` `types` and `export` fields. Just kept `index.d.ts` from which I import and export types and doing `import { MyType } from '@acme/types'` seems to work

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850348/how-to-create-a-types-only-package-on-npm?noredirect=1#comment133803053_75850348) @eakl Would you like to see that as an answer — or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes please. Go on with the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Declaration Files > Publishing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) in the TypeScript handbook for information related to this topic, and check out the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/definitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) for lots of examples.

---

In a simple scenario like the one described by the details in your question, the only parts needed in the provider package are:

1. the type declaration files, including an entrypoint declaration file named `index.d.ts`, and
2. the minimum criteria for meeting the definition of a Node.js module: a [`package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#modules-packages) manifest file with the [required fields](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file#required-name-and-version-fields): `name` and `version`

So, given that your provider package directory is located at `./provider`, the required files would look like this:

`./provider/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/types",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

`./provider/index.d.ts`:

```ts
export type MyType = {
  name: string;
};
```

The following note is included in the linked TS handbook page, in the section *[Including declarations in your npm package](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package)*:

> Also note that if your main declaration file is named `index.d.ts` and lives at the root of the package you do not need to mark the `types` property, though it is advisable to do so.

So, you might consider defining that field explicitly rather than relying on automatic resolution behavior:

`./provider/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/types",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

---

Now, that's the answer to the question asked — but I'll also include an example consumer package with reproduction steps for demonstration.

> If you want to follow along, you can copy + paste each of the following example files, recreating them in your filesystem. Or you can just run this script in your browser's JS console to download a zip archive of the entire project structure:
>
> ```js
> (() => {
>   function createBase64DataUrl(mediaType, b64Str) {
>     return `data:${mediaType};base64,${b64Str}`;
>   }
>
>   function download(url, fileName) {
>     const a = document.createElement("a");
>     a.href = url;
>     a.download = fileName;
>     a.click();
>     a.remove();
>   }
>
>   const zipArchiveData = "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";
>   const dataUrl = createBase64DataUrl("application/zip", zipArchiveData);
>   download(dataUrl, "so-75850348.zip");
> })();
> ```

Given that the consumer package directory is located at `./consumer`, it might start with this minimal package file:

`./consumer/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

The first step is to install TypeScript and the provider types package as development dependencies:

```txt
$ cd ./consumer
$ npm install --save-dev typescript ../provider

added 2 packages, and audited 4 packages in 616ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

> Each package could have been installed using separate commands:
>
> ```sh
> npm install --save-dev typescript
> npm install --save-dev ../provider
> ```

Afterward, the `package.json` will include these dependencies:

```json
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@acme/types": "file:../provider",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

We want to use the types in some code, so let's create a basic TypeScript file which will use the types from the package:

`./consumer/index.ts`:

```ts
import type { MyType } from "@acme/types";

const obj: MyType = { name: "foo" };

console.log(obj);
```

Next, let's add an [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts) to the `package.json` file which will compile the TypeScript file using the compiler defaults — we'll name the script `compile`:

```json
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@acme/types": "file:../provider",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc index.ts"
  }
}
```

> In most scenarios you'll probably want to configure the compiler behavior for your project using a [TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Now, let's compile the file and run it:

```txt
$ npm run compile && node index.js

> consumer@0.1.0 compile
> tsc index.ts

{ name: 'foo' }
```

Compilation succeeds without issue and the file runs as expected.

> Note that I'm using this Node LTS version as I write this answer:
>
> ```txt
> $ node --version
> v18.15.0
> ```

Comment: This is brilliant and crazy-helpful, @jsejcksn. Any chance you might add the ways in which the pattern is different if you're declaring your types package in an npm workspace configuration? I _think_ all that's different is adding `"workspaces": ["packages/provider"]` to the parent package.json. Then `npm i` should symlink from there? I think?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850348/how-to-create-a-types-only-package-on-npm/75859999?noredirect=1#comment136914606_75859999) @XML Glad it was helpful. That's really a separate question, but why don't you [try it and find out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/438273)? [Here's a link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/workspaces) to the documentation for npm's workspaces feature.

Comment: Already in-progress! So far, so good, but I have yet to finish consuming elsewhere...

Comment: BTW, I appreciate your gentle suggestion to try it and find out, and was already doing so. Just wanted to see if you had any immediate material on it, given your clear expertise in this domain, and if that would be helpful to other readers of this post...

Comment: @jsejcksn excellent answer. What would change if the types exported by provider depends on one consumer file to be statically generated? maybe use postinstall script? how about a watch script?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850348/how-to-create-a-types-only-package-on-npm/75859999?noredirect=1#comment137109189_75859999) @leog The provider package cannot depend on the details of a consuming package — that would be a circular dependency. If you have a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @jsejcksn done at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773213/how-to-create-a-types-only-npm-package-dependent-on-consumer-file